# открытие нового окна - Window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery

созрел вопрос как сделать чтобы пользователю открывался сайт

```
 window.open("ссылка");
```

но при этом вкладка в которой сайт откроется не подсвечивалась
чтобы пользователь был на сайте и паралельно открылась вкладка,есть ли такая возможность ? или она в любом случае откроется?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var popup = window.open(...);
popup.blur();
window.focus();
```

Но если у пользователя в браузере настроено открытие вкладки в фокусе, то вам ничего не поможет